# Using mysqldump when host is set to characters not numbers

Tags: sql, database, mysql

I am trying to use mysqldump, but I am having an error with it, my host isn't set to an ip, but instead it is set up to be something different, it is set up to be like db1, db2, etc...

Some things I have tried, but haven't worked.
$ mysqldump --host=db1 -u User -pPassword dbname > db.sql

$ mysqldump -h db1 -u User -pPassword dbname > db.sql

I can connect perfectly whenever I use my db1 as host, but I am just having problem using mysqldump.

Thank you all so much for your help and ideas on how to fix this.

Comment: so you connect from a different host to do the mysqldump ?

Comment: post the compled error message

Comment: It just goes to the next line, but never completes the dump. It creates an empty file called db.sql. There is no error message.

Comment: try the mysql client : $ mysql -h db1 -u User -pPassword dbname   , and see the errormessage

Comment: That worked, thank you so much, very much appreciated!!!